# Why is USB Serial so fast in linux?

Tags: linux, usb, modem, linux-kernel, serial-port

I've just started using a 3G modem on a RaspberryPi using the "stock" USB Serial driver from the linux kernel (as indicated in the modem documentation).
Once the modem was recognized and appeared as a serial USB (`/dev/ttyUSB[0-4]`) I could use it with `pppd call [module]` which uses the serial device to create a network interface usable by the whole system.

Then, once `pppd` is started and everything looks fine, I can ping/download/whatever using common tools. But when I download a big image, I have download rates of about 300-400KiB/s. How is that even possible, since I asked pppd to start a 115200 Baud serial connection??? (115200 b/s should give me a THEORETICAL top speed of 10KiB/s). Compression is also disabled in the serial connection.

Which leads to my question: what does this driver really do? Is any hardware part of the connection actually serial (asynchronous?) ? If not, why is it called serial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no actual serial link to run at 115,200 baud or any other baud rate. The interface a serial link would provide is emulated to allow the modem to work with software designed to work with an actual serial link.

Comment: In other words: this particular serial interface simply ignores the "baud rate" since it isn't *really* a UART.

Comment: There might not actually be a serial interface (other than the USB link). It may well be parallel with all the devices inside the same chip.

Comment: Thanks. It still doesn't make sense to call it a "Serial" USB in my opinion. It's more like "USB character device". FTDI adaptors translate this synchronous connection (and actually asynchronize it) but the general use case is just a USB connection where characters can be read and written.